# How to find most significant bit (MSB)

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I want to know which value the first bit of a byte has.

For example:

I have `byte m = (byte) 0x8C;`

How could I know if the first bit is an 1 or a 0 ?

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: What does "first" mean, specifically?

Comment: If you want the position of the first 1, from the left: use Integer.numberOfLeadingZeroes

Answer (score 24):

It depends what you mean by "first bit". If you mean "most significant bit" you can use:

```
// 0 or 1
int msb = (m & 0xff) >> 7;
```

Or if you don't mind the values being 0x80 or 0, just use:

```
// 0 or 0x80
int msb = m & 0x80;
```

Or in fact, as a `boolean`:

```
// Uses the fact that byte is signed using 2s complement
// True or false
boolean msb = m < 0;
```

If you mean the least significant bit, you can just use:

```
// 0 or 1
int lsb = m & 1;
```

Comment: It was the most significant bit. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Jon I don't understand the first one why it's `0xff`? `0x80` is enough. I think the right way to do it is `int msb = (m & 0x80) >>> 7;`.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Yes, that would be fine. I just habitually convert byte to int by masking with 0xff :)

Comment: @Jon but still doesn't make sense for me. However, more simple way to do it is `int msb = -(m >> 7);` ;)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad: Well it's still going to have the same result, isn't it? (Masking with 0xff I mean.)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean leftmost bit, bitwise and it with 0x80 and check if it is zero nor not:

```
public boolean isFirstBitSet(byte b) {
    System.out.println((b & (byte)0x80));
    return (b & (byte)0x80) < 0;
}
```

If you mean lowest order bit you will need to and with 0x01 and check a different condition:

```
public boolean isFirstBitSet(byte b) {
    System.out.println((b & (byte)0x01));
    return (b & (byte)0x80) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If the first bit is the lowest bit (ie bit 0), then

```
if((m & 1) >0) ...
```

should do it.

In general,

```
if ((m & (1<<N)) > 0) ...
```

will give you whether or not bit `N` is set.
If, however, you meant the highest bit (bit 7), then use N=7.

Answer (score 1):

Use the bitwise and operator.

```
public class BitExample {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        byte m = (byte)0x8C;
        System.out.println("The first bit is " + (m & (byte)0x01));
        m = (byte)0xFF;
        System.out.println("The first bit is " + (m & (byte)0x01));
    }
}

// output is...
The first bit is 0
The first bit is 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Its a bit of a hack but you can use

```
if(x >> -1 != 0) // top bit set.
```

This works for `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long` data types.

However for most types the simplest approach is to compare with 0

```
if (x < 0) // top bit set.
```

This works for `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, or `double`

(Ignoring negative zero and negative NaN, most people do ;)

For `char` type you need to know the number of bits. ;)

```
if (ch >>> 15 != 0) // top bit set.
```

Answer (score 0):

> This code gives you msb(most significant bit)/biggest number which is a
> power of 2 and less than any given number.

```
class msb{
void main(){
        int n=155;//let 110001010
        int l=(Integer.toBinaryString(n)).length();//9
        String w="0"+Integer.toBinaryString(i).substring(1);//010001010
        i=Integer.parseInt(w,2);
        System.out.println(n^i);//110001010^010001010=100000000
}
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In general, the Most significant bit (MSB) is the bit in a multiple-bit binary number with the largest value.

To find the MSB, you can use

```java
int msb = Integer.highestOneBit(n);
```

> n = 11 (1011) will give 8 (1000)

To find the position of the MSB, you can use

```java
int mostSigBitPosition(int n) {
    return 32 - Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n);
}
```

> n = 11 (1011) will give you 4 (if we index bits from 1, the MSB is at position 4)

Where `Integer.highestOneBit(n)` and `Integer.numberOfLeadingZeros(n)` are `java.lang.Integer` class's methods

```java
int highestOneBit(int i) {
    return i & (0x80000000 >>> numberOfLeadingZeros(i));
}
```

```java
int numberOfLeadingZeros(int i) {
  if (i <= 0)
    return i == 0 ? 32 : 0;
  int n = 31;a
  if (i >= 1 << 16) { n -= 16; i >>>= 16; }
  if (i >= 1 <<  8) { n -=  8; i >>>=  8; }
  if (i >= 1 <<  4) { n -=  4; i >>>=  4; }
  if (i >= 1 <<  2) { n -=  2; i >>>=  2; }
  return n - (i >>> 1);
}
```